# PHP Yii2 Datagridview colum info

Tags: datagridview, yii2

I try to show in one column from my datagridview but the relation doesn't work. The column its empty.

In my model my relation is.

```
  public function getStatus0()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Status::className(), ['id' => 'status']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTicketsInfos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TicketsInfo::className(), ['id_ticket' => 'id']);
}
```

and my view is this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => ''],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
  //      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
          //'attribute' => 'id',
          'label' => 'Numero del Ticket',
          'value' => 'id'
        ],
        //'status0.nombre',
        [
          'attribute' => 'status',
          'label' => 'Estatus del Incidente',
          'value' => 'status0.nombre'
        ],
        'fecha_inicio',
        'fecha_cierre',
        'ticketsInfos.nombre_creador',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => ' {CERRAR}',
        'buttons' => [
            'CERRAR' => function($url, $model, $key) {
              if ($model->status == 1){
                return Html::button('CERRAR TICKET', ['class' => 'reset','id'=> 'confirmar'.$model->id]);
              }
              else if ($model->status == 0) {
               return Html::a('PENDIENTE');
             } else {
               return Html::a('CERRADO');
             }
            }
        ]
      ],
    ],
```

The relation with status0.nombre its fine but i have problem with ticketsInfos.nombre_creado, in my model the property its the follow:

- @property Status $status0
- @property TicketsInfo[] $ticketsInfos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No surprise I guess: you are referencing a hasMany relation, so you don't get a single object, you get an array with relation ticketsInfos. So which nombre_creador should be shown here?

A dumb solution might be to create the column this way:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'columns' => [ 
        ...
        [
            'label'  => 'Nombre Creador',
            'format' => 'raw'
            'value'  => function($model) {
                return implode('<br>', \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(
                    $model->ticketsInfos, 
                    'nombre_creador'
                ));
            } 
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]);
```

I don't know if this sufficient. Maybe the data shouldn't be displayed in the GridView, rather on a view page for a single model.

If you do something like this then you should load the data with [`with`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface#with()-detail): `->with('ticketsInfos')`. Otherwise for each row another query will be executed. See [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading) for more. You could put this in your search model class that creates the `$dataProvider`.

Hope that makes sense. Did not test it.

Comment: @CarlosDeseda In that case I would recommend to rename *ticketsInfos* to *ticketInfo*. Especially with relations I find it useful if you can tell by the name that you get one or possibly more objects.

Comment: Ok!! Thanks for the recommendation!